# Search for Keyword in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use an ajax-call to get the html from an external url:

```
 var uriData = $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.example.com', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });
```

That works fine. I get an alert with html of an external website.

Is there a easy way to search for a keyword and count the number of it in the Text or in the headlines of the html-body?

I tried it this way:

**HTML**

```
<input id="url" type="text" name="url">
<input id="keyword" type="text" name="keyword">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 function keyWords() {
   var website = jQuery('#url').val(); 
   var keyword = jQuery('#keyword').val(); 

   jQuery.ajax({ url: website, success: function(data) { 
   var sumKeyword = data.split(keyword).length - 1;    
   alert (sumKeyword); } 
   });
 };
```

But unfortunately he then searches the keyword in the entire HTML. (for e.g. also in achor text etc.) Finally, I want to get the number of keywords in headlines and in the text (p, span,  etc.)

Comment: You could match the body part "<body>...</body>" with an match data.match(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/)

Comment: Can you include a sample of the html returned? You are referring to headlines - there is no such element in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a chunk of code that might inspire you to solve your problem

```
   var data='<span id="url" type="text" name="url">test this test</span>';
    var message = $('<div/>').append(data).find("span:contains('test')").each(function(){

       var sumKeyword = $(this).text().split("test").length - 1;  
       alert (sumKeyword); 

    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2fhjhet/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the match function:

```
jQuery.ajax({ url: website, success: function(data) {
   var body = data.match(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/)[1];
   var sumKeyword = body.split(keyword).length - 1;    
   alert (sumKeyword); } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

getting the textual out of the boilerplate of an HTML is a common task tackled by multiple external APIs and libraries. You cannot simply get the textual content by checking all the text in a webpage as you will end up with lots of irrelevant advertisements and so on.
Using libraries like Diffbot can identify the title/header and the body and suggest some tags and keywords. Afterwards you can do your analysis on the extracted text.

**External APIs**

- [Diffbot](http://www.diffbot.com/)
- [Alchemy](http://www.alchemyapi.com/)
- [readability: Turn any web page into a clean view](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-readability)
- [textract: Node module for extracting text from
  various file types](https://github.com/dbashford/textract)
- [unfluff: Automatically extract body content (and other cool stuff) from an html document](https://github.com/ageitgey/node-unfluff)
- [Scrapely: A pure-python HTML screen-scraping library](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely)
- [Scrape.it: Copy data from any website](https://scrape.it/)
- [Boilerpipe: Boilerplate Removal and Fulltext Extraction from HTML pages](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/)

Comment: Thank you all, I will try your solutions and come back later!